# Move focus to a particular field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a button that will add show a form on the page. how can I move the focus to the first field of the form when that button is clicked?

simple example:

HTML:

```
<form style="display:none;" id="newForm">
   <input type="text" id="firstField">
</form>
<input type="button" id="showForm" value="add new">
```

jQuery:

```
 $("#showForm").click(function(){
     $("#newForm").show();
     //move focus??
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It might be this:

```
$("#newForm input:first").focus();
```

Answer (score 7):

A quicker lookup would simply be.

```
$('#firstField').focus()
```

However if you removed the ID from your element then this would be better but slightly slower.

```
$('#newForm input:first').focus();
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('input#firstfield').focus();
```